# We have to cover all branches with all Control-Flow expressions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, control-flow

I looked at [the docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html) from Kotlin website, there are only two Control-Flow expressions: `if` and `when`.

#### For `if`:

> the expression is required to have an `else` branch

#### For `when`:

> The `else` branch is evaluated if none of the other branch conditions are satisfied. If `when` is used as an expression, the `else` branch is mandatory, unless the compiler can prove that all possible cases are covered with branch conditions.

### Question

So it seems that there is no way to make a Control-Flow expression without covering all branches, Is it right? If not, Is there any way to make a Control-Flow expression to miss some branches; If so, why?

---

Following code will occur `if must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression`

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    intent?.let {
        if (it.action == MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGIN) {
            mListener.get()?.loggedOn(LoggedOnUserInfo.IT)
        }else if (it.action == MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGOUT) {
            // Occur 'if must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression'
            mListener.get()?.loggedOut(LoggedOutUserInfo())
        }
    }
}
```

But following code pass compile.....

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    intent?.let {
        if (it.action == MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGIN) {
            mListener.get()?.loggedOn(LoggedOnUserInfo.IT)
            context!!.unregisterReceiver(this) // only add this line to test.
        }else if (it.action == MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGOUT) {
            mListener.get()?.loggedOut(LoggedOutUserInfo())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, unless the if or when is used as an expression. As in `val foo = if (someCondition) "bar" else "baz"`.

Comment: in the document, it has "*If you're using if as an expression rather than a statement (for example, returning its value or assigning it to a variable), the expression is required to have an else branch.*" [doc](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression), so it seems that when you are using `if` as statement, it won't require `else`.

Comment: so maybe "*In Kotlin, if is an expression*" is wrong, and "*In Kotlin, if can be used both as expression and statement*" is correct.

Comment: @JBNizet and ymonad, thanks you all guys, you are right. But I still have some confuse with this issue, so I add my source code to the question, which make me confuse and lead me have to ask this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick here is not to use the `if` as an expression. My guess is that you placed the `if` at a `let` block, which returns its last statement, thus using the "result" of the `if`, thus treating it as an expression.

I suggest throwing away the `let` function (it is useless anyway here):

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    if(intent != null) {
        if (intent.action == MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGIN) {
            mListener.get()?.loggedOn(LoggedOnUserInfo.IT)
        } else if (intent.action == MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGOUT) {
            mListener.get()?.loggedOut(LoggedOutUserInfo())
        }
    }
}
```

Your second version compiles because `context!!.unregisterReceiver(this)` has a different type than `mListener.get()?.loggedOut(LoggedOutUserInfo())`, which makes the types mismatch and prevents using the `if` as an expression.

#### P.S.

Kotlin has quite a few powerful control structures. I personally prefer this version:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    intent ?: return
    when(intent.action) {
        MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGIN -> mListener.get()?.loggedOn(LoggedOnUserInfo.IT)
        MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGOUT -> mListener.get()?.loggedOut(LoggedOutUserInfo())
    }
}
```

Comment: I would personally avoid `?: return` because it is much harder to distinguish control flow visually. I had a couple of "happy debugging" hours with it.

Comment: @SerCe really? Could you share your experience (maybe at Slack at #random)? We are kinda in the middle of a fight whether this idiom is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 1):

> So it seems that there is no way to make a Control-Flow expression
>   without covering all branches, Is it right?

Yes

In the second case

```
mListener.get()?.loggedOn(LoggedOnUserInfo.IT)
context!!.unregisterReceiver(this)
```

Is not an expression anymore, the whole `if` block is a statement. 
However, you can also provide `else` with `Unit` in a first case if you really need an expression:

```
if (it.action == MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGIN) {
    mListener.get()?.loggedOn(LoggedOnUserInfo.IT)
} else if (it.action == MySDK.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGOUT) {
    // Occur 'if must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression'
    mListener.get()?.loggedOut(LoggedOutUserInfo())
} else Unit
```

But it would be better to avoid this code because it is less readable.