# 'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin, conditional-statements

I have the code below working before, now compiler halts and marks both `if` statements and says:

**'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression**

But as you see this is not an expression, but just a simple equality statement and a conditional statement next to it.

```
try {
    val json_string = responseBody!!.string()
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(json_string)
    if (jsonObject.has("version")) {

        val remoteVersion = jsonObject.getInt("version")
        if (remoteVersion > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE) {
            handler.post {
                showInstallNewVersionDialog()
            }
        }
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.message?.let { Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.message!!) }

}
```

The funny part is if I added empty `else` tags, it will run but will warn to remove empty `else` statements:

```
if (jsonObject.has("version")) {

    val remoteVersion = jsonObject.getInt("version")
    if (remoteVersion > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE) {
        handler.post {
            showInstallNewVersionDialog()
        }
    } else {}
} else {}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839544/we-have-to-cover-all-branches-with-all-control-flow-expressions-in-kotlin

Comment: Are you by any chance returning from the if which would cascade to the try? Can we have a look at the whole method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If IDE tells you that `'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression` then it is so. Most likely this try-catch construction is defined as a custom getter of a variable or as [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions).

An example:

```
val aVariable =
    try {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() == 0L) {
            println("It is 1970-01-01")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // empty
    }

fun aFunction() =
    try {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() == 0L) {
            println("It is 1970-01-01")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // empty
    }
```

And the IDE (lint) shows me an error even before compiling. Same error for the function.

[image: Error message]

To fix this issue you either introduce else statement OR redeclare this variable as a function (or update the function you have). This function will work fine as it always returns `Unit` even if you do not have any code in it.

```
fun aFunction() {
    try {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() == 0L) {
            println("It is 1970-01-01")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // empty
    }
}
```

When you use single-expression functions or getters you **MUST** return a value. That is why `else` part is required.

Comment: How can this be the solution? I can't see that it matches the question. There is no variable assignment. I have the same problem. I have a response handler for Retrofit request where I checked some local values. If they are null I don't have to do everything I could with the response data. Worked perfect. Until I recognized that I have to catch HTTP exception if I don't want the app to crash if the login expired. As soon as I surrounded my "if" with "try{..}" the IDE tells me to add "else" branches. If I add "else {}" everything works as expected but code inspection complains about empty body.

Comment: "There is no variable assignment" - I assumed that the code mentioned in question either returns the result to a variable or returns something from a function because this exact error can occur in such situations. Does your response handler of a Retrofit request expected to return anything? There is a chanse you've found a bug in IDE or lint.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan If you wish you can share your code so I can take a look at it. Maybe I'll be able to point out the issue.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu Can i just return false there?
IDE says YES :)

Comment: @AlexS Not sure what exactly you are asking but you can have a return statement **after** an `if` statement without `else` branch. That would be absolutely valid. You can imagine your function or getter in a variable as a roadmap where you always start at the same point. Each route from that starting point must have a value at the end in order for you to get a value back when you call your function or variable. 
Compilers and linters check that for us and raise an exception when this roadmap has a route without a value at the end. Computer would not know what to do with absence of value.

Comment: Down code below work for me: 
... catch{
        // empty
    }

Thanks for suggested way to solve!

Answer (score 10):

The issue is that Kotlin sees `try {} catch {}` construct as a "function" that returns a value, which is not the same as Java `try {} catch {}`.
As a result compiler assumes that you "forgot" to code the `else` branches even if it is clearly the case of you not wanting to return any value.
Kotlin sometimes is ludicrous.

i.e. you can write:

```
val t = try {
  "test"
} catch (e: Exception) {
  "error"
}
println(t)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the cause and not trying to justify why to blindly follow a seemingly irrational error message.

Comment: I get the compile error on an if inside of the body of someNullableVariable?.let { ... }
Then when I add an empty 'else {}' statement, the code compiles but now the IDE Lint warns me that I have an empty else.

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, "Kotlin sometimes is ludicrous".  In my case I was trying to do something in the catch statement:

```
fun x() {
  try {
    doSomething()
    doSomethingIfNoException()
  } catch (e:Exception) {
     if(c) doSomethingForException()
     else ""
  }
}
```

Kotlin insisted on the else in the catch.  Putting the else"" was the easiest fix I could find.